# Error 500 with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I've got this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?drobgen.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1drobgen.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|swf|xml|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ rewrite.php [L,NS]
```

When I hit the website I got error 500. 
Can you tell me what can be wrong with this `.htaccess` file?
I use it locally and this works great.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, 500 errors are server side, not client-side, so get in touch with your host.

See here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: yes but usually it is thrown when you got problems with htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP as a cgi, put .htaccess file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

in cgi-bin directory. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your last rewrite rule should be split into a rewrite condition and a rewriterule, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?drobgen.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1drobgen.pl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|ico|swf|xml|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php [L,NS]
```